# Is it possible to format individual characters in a cell?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I would like to format individual characters inside an Excel cell using Office-JS.

What I need for example : **c**cc

What I get is: **ccc**

My Code:

```
var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A25");
var range = range.load(["text", "values"]);

return context.sync().then(function() {
  console.log("Values" + range.values);

  range.text
    .toString()
    .substring(0, 1)
    .fontsize(34); // not working
});
```

});

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: U don’t understand the question?

Comment: What have you tried, what do want to achieve till now kindly share some code thanks

Comment: I Hope now is better

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to let you know that this is not supported yet. You can set one cell format like below way but for part of words in a cell cannot be formatted with api now

```js
 const range = sheet.getRange("B2:E2");
    range.set({
        format: {
            fill: {
                color: "#4472C4"
            },
            font: {
                name: "Verdana",
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    })
    range.format.autofitColumns();
```